# Reformatting Hard Drive

Tags: administrator

I have a work laptop with Windows 7 Pro installed. I'm leaving this job and handing back my laptop. I have a lot of work that I have done on it and have the IP for this work. I'd like to reformat the hard drive before returning to delete my personal files and work. Unfortunately, I don't have admin rights to access this feature. Is it possible to reformat without logging in as an administrator?

Comment: Can you boot this computer using a CD/DVD disk or USB drive? If not, can you access BIOS settings?

Comment: No. The laptop and its contents do not belong to you. This is normally done by the IT department when they get the laptop back.

Comment: @Burgi: I think that depends on the local law -- afaik at least in some places the author still has full ownership. I mean, if they haven't _already_ given the files to the employer in some way. (Side personal project, maybe?)

Comment: I would be careful about doing anything as you don't know what environment your system runs in and you could damage the machine. Also deleting work is usually treated like you've damaged equipment if not worse. Leave it to the professionals, they will wipe all your data that is not business pertinent.

Comment: @grawity if it's on a work machine regardless of it it's personal project or not, it belongs to the company hence. You should check the intellectual property clause of your contract it will no doubt cover it!

Comment: Ideally you should not touch the OS. The laptop with its OS is the property of the company. Generally you are allowed to use it for business purposes as long as you in employment with that company. I am m assuming that the security policy has blocked CD/DVD & USB Mass storage on that laptop. Assuming you can access the internet from that laptop, look for a freeware and potable data eraser that just runs standalone and does not require any installation. Based on how it works, you can either wipe free space or specific files.

Answer (score 3):

> **I have a lot of work that I have done on it and have the IP for this work.**

It is a mistake to put your property on a computer that belongs to someone else.

Normally, the work a programmer does on company-provided equipment belongs to the company unless you have some specific contract terms that say otherwise.

You need to be very careful not to destroy something the company paid you to produce - otherwise you might find you have committed criminal damages which the company could bring you to court with. Having a criminal record for this type of crime can obviously wreck your future employability.

> **I'd like to reformat the hard drive**

Just *overwrite* your personal files in which the company has no interest, once with zeroes is enough for normal hard disks. Then delete them.

You can also clear unused space using tools like `cipher /W:C` on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Within the OS? No, that's the whole point of "administrator" rights.

However, since you have physical access, you could boot *another* OS, be it a Windows rescue disk or a Linux live CD, and reformat the disk from there. Check if the laptop allows changing the boot order, i.e. booting from a CD or USB.

Alternatively you could disassemble the laptop and connect its disk to another computer (on which you already have admin rights), and reformat it from there. Afaik, laptops and desktops use the same kind of SATA connection nowadays?

---

Note that a simple "reformat" might not help much. Most of the time it only erases as much as needed to make the disk *look* empty – which is about the same as just deleting the files, in terms of recoverability.

You would have better luck with dedicated "disk wipe" programs – run any kind of 1-pass or 2-pass erase on the disk. (Anything more than 2-pass is overkill.)

Enabling BitLocker *might* also help – I don't know if it encrypts the whole disk as soon as enabled.

Comment: I wouldn't of posted an answer for this as if the user doesn't have admin rights there is a reason for it. Also as stated above it's not his machine and to be fair he shouldn't be using work equipment for personal use, so anything on there should belong to the company (as per every company's contract of employment)

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys. Legalities/ethics aside, is it possible to reformat the hard drive without admin rights?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please actually read the post. Thanks in advance.